# git_clone error message Assertion failed: git_atomic_get(&git__n_inits) > 0

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, libgit2

When I tried to do `git_clone()` (using libgit2), this error message occured

> Assertion failed: git_atomic_get(&git__n_inits) > 0, file C:\data\Install\Git\libgit2-0.25.1\src\global.c, line 199

My program is interrupted by Visual Studio:

> R6010 - abort() has been called

There is my code :

---

```
git_repository *cloned_repo = NULL;

cout << all_urls.at(num).c_str() << " -> " << clone_to.at(num).c_str() << endl;

int error = git_clone(&cloned_repo, all_urls.at(num).c_str(),clone_to.at(num).c_str(), &clone_opts);

if (error != 0) {
    const git_error *err = giterr_last();

    cerr << "error in clone num " << num << " -> message :" << err->message << endl;
}

else cout << endl << "Clone " << num << " succesful" << "(from url : " << all_urls.at(num) << " " << "to path : " << clone_to.at(num) << ")" << endl;

git_repository_free(cloned_repo);
```

---

I have properly set `clone_opts` (credentials), so I really do not know where is the problem. I have done `git_clone()` in different projects before, and I did it this way, but I hadn't had such errors before.

Thanks

Comment: Have you used a debugger?

Comment: Yes, problem is line 

int error = git_clone(&cloned_repo, all_urls.at(num).c_str(),clone_to.at(num).c_str(), &clone_opts);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to call the functions `git_libgit2_init()` and `git_libgit2_shutdown()` in this method. I called it in previous methods and I thought I don't have to do that also there.

Comment: You should only call `git_libgit2_shutdown()` right before exiting you application, or if you **really** need to release the global resources.